# How to specify .csv delimiter while using Map()

Tags: r

I have a `list` containing 2 or more `dataframes`:

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=letters[1:3])
f <- data.frame(x=11:13, y=letters[11:13])
df <- list(d, f)
```

to save them as `.csv`, I use the following syntax:

```
filenames = paste0('C:/Output_', names(df), '.csv')
Map(write.csv, df, filenames)
```

But I would like to add some strings to obtain a specific format, like:

```
quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep = "\t", na = "", col.names = FALSE
```

And the thing is that I am not that sure where to add that syntax. Wherever I try, I get a `warning` saying my syntax has been ignored.

```
> Warning messages:
1: In (function (...)  : attempt to set 'col.names' ignored
2: In (function (...)  : attempt to set 'sep' ignored
3: In (function (...)  : attempt to set 'col.names' ignored
4: In (function (...)  : attempt to set 'sep' ignored
```

Any suggestions? In `BaseR` preferably!

Comment: You need to use an anonymous function in order to specify further arguments

Comment: Your example uses `names(df)`, but `names(df)` is NULL ..

Comment: `write.csv` is a special-case of `write.table`, meaning it pre-defines a set of arguments. If you want to change them, use `write.table` instead, and your warning should go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use anonymous function in order to be able to pass further arguments, i.e.

```
Map(function(...) write.csv(..., quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep = "\t", na = ""), df, filenames)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But `col.names` argument is still ignored... I get a warning everytime.

Comment: I think you need `write.table()` as `write.csv` does not have the `col.names` argument

Answer (score 5):

Why you're still getting `col.names` warnings: farther down in the documentation (`?write.csv`) you'll see

> These wrappers [write.csv and write.csv2] are deliberately inflexible: they are designed to
>        ensure that the correct conventions are used to write a valid
>        file.  Attempts to change ‘append’, ‘col.names’, ‘sep’, ‘dec’ or
>        ‘qmethod’ are ignored, with a warning.

Should go away if you use `write.table()` instead.

Comment: You both deserve it, but if you say so, then I'm changing it. Once again, thank you!!

Comment: You sir are too kind :)